# Is there any way to bundle HTML/CSS/IMAGES?

Tags: html, css

I am pretty new to web design, so this may be a very elementary question. I have a folder where I have multiple HTML files for a simple web page, I also have CSS style sheets and JPGs for the web backgrounds. I want to send the sample website to my friends via email, but there are about 10 files in a folder. Is there any way to bundle them to make it simpler for a non-programmer to open and view the website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: No.

You should really just send them a zip folder containing the different HTML files, CSS files, and images. That way they can just decompress the zip, open up the default document (i'm guessing index.html) and view the website locally on their machine. If you'd like further explanation please let me know.

Comment: Is that also how it works when I am about to publish the website to the server?

Comment: Yes - you would upload all of the html files, css files, and images to the root folder on your webserver.

Comment: Thanks for the help!